# Embedding Trendnet TV-IP512P into a web page?

Tags: internet-explorer, camera, ip, embed, mjpeg

Ive been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to embed a live stream of my Trendnet IP camera (Model: TV-IP512P) into an HTML or PHP webpage.

My problem is that I've managed to embed a live stream by using an img tag.

```
<img id="mjpgImage" alt="Processing..." width="0" height="0" src="http://guest:guest@herrings.dyndns.org:8282/video/mjpg.cgi?profileid=3" style="width: 640px; height: 480px; padding-top: 25px; padding-right: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px; padding-left: 25px; "/>
```

This works in all the web browsers except Internet Explorer (big surprise there.)

Does anyone know of a way that I could get this to work in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solutions!

Ive tried other methods of displaying the mjpg feed by using JavaScript but I had no luck getting it to work.

But then I found [www.charliemouse.com/code/cambozola](http://www.charliemouse.com/code/cambozola/)

It was super easy to setup, just follow the instructions on their page.